# Number of points of discontinuity of $f(x)=\text{sgn}(\sin^2 x-\sin x-1)$ in $x\in(0,4\pi)$

Tags: functions

Number of points of discontinuity of $f(x)=\text{sgn}(\sin^2 x-\sin x-1)$ in $x\in(0,4\pi)$

Attempt for a solution

$$\text{sgn}(\sin^2 x-\sin x-1)$$

$$=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1\;\;, \;\sin^2x-\sin x-1<0\\\\
 +0\;\;,\; \sin^2 x-\sin x-1=0 \\\\
 1\;\;,\; \sin^2x-\sin x-1>0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

but $\sin^2x -\sin x-1=\bigg(\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2-\frac{5}{4}$

How i approches that problem from that point . Help me please

Comment: It's nothing to add here. Either the solution is meant to be zero or it is a typo in the condition.

Comment: Sorry AT my bad . i have edited it.

Comment: Did you try solving $\sin^2x-\sin x-1=0$  to find where it is positive and negative on the interval?

Answer (score 1):

For all $x \in \mathbb R$ we have

$$\sin^2x -\sin x+1=\bigg(\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2+\frac{3}{4}>0.$$

Hence $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and therefore $f$ is continuous on $ \mathbb R$.

Comment: @ Fred I have edited my problem .please see it

Comment: @Jacky: In general you should not edit the question after you already received an answer. Please be more careful next time when you formulate a question.

Comment: OK MrYouMath.....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the third binomial formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$:

$$\sin^2x -\sin x-1=\bigg(\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2-\frac{5}{4}=(\sin x-1/2-\sqrt{5}/2)(\sin x-1/2+\sqrt{5}/2).$$

Now, we know a product of two numbers is positive if both have the same sign. And we know that the product is negative if both numbers have opposite signs. It is zero if at least one of the numbers is equal to zero.

Can you solve it from here?